# Prove $|g(x)|\le M$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $g_n\to g$ in $L^1$ in $X$. Assume that for every measurable set $K$
$\lim sup_{n\to\infty}|\int_Kg_ndm|\le M\cdot m(K)$. Prove that $|g(x)|\le M$ a.e.

I am thinking using a subsequence $\{{g_n}_i\}$ of $\{g_n\}$ s.t. $\lim sup_{n\to\infty}|\int_Kg_ndm|=\lim_{n_i\to\infty}|\int_K{g_n}_idm|$. And by $g_n\to g$ in $L^1$ we can get ${g_n}_i\to g$ in $L^1$, thus there is a subsequence ${{g_n}_i}_j\to g$ a.e. If we we replace ${{g_n}_i}_j$ by $f_j$ then we have $f_j\to g$ in $L^1$ a.e. and for every measurable set $K$
$ |\lim\int_Kf_idm|=\lim |\int_Kf_idm|\le M\cdot m(K)$.

Now I want to show $\int_Kgdm\le M\cdot m(K)$ but I am stuck on that.
Moreover, how do we deduce $|g(x)|\le M$ a.e. from $\int_Kgdm\le M\cdot m(K)$?

Comment: To your last question, consider the sets $K_{\epsilon} \equiv \{x \in X | g(x) \geq M+\epsilon \}$. What could we say if $m(K_{\epsilon})>0$? What does this imply about the measure of $\{x \in X | g(x) \geq M\}$? Can you work out the corresponding argument for $g(x) \leq -M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any measurable set $K$, consider that

$$\left| \int_K g_n - \int_K g \right| = \left| \int_K (g_n-g) \right| \leq \int_K |g_n-g| \leq \int_X |g_n-g| = \|g_n-g\|_1 \to 0, $$

so $\int_K g_n \to \int_K g$, showing that the limit of $|\int_K g_n|$ exists and hence is equal to its limsup. Thus we have

$$\left | \int_K g \right | = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left | \int_K g_n \right | =\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left | \int_K g_n \right | \leq M \cdot m(K).$$

Consider the sets $K^\pm_n \equiv \{x \in X | \pm g(x) \geq M+\frac{1}{n}\}$ (so this separately defines $K^+_n$ and $K^-_n$). If $m(K^\pm_n) \neq 0$, then $\pm \int_{K^\pm_n} g \geq (M+\frac{1}{n}) \cdot m(K^\pm_n) > M \cdot m(K^\pm_n)$, a contradiction to the above, so we must have $m(K^\pm_n)=0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Setting $K^\pm \equiv \{x \in X | \pm g(x) \geq M\} = \cup_n K^\pm_n$, then we see that $m(K^\pm)=0$ by continuity of the measure, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to go to a subsequence which converges a.e.. Since $g_n \to g$ in $L^{1}$ we have $\int_K g dm=\lim \int_K g_n dm$ so $|\int_K g dm| \leq M m(K)$. [ $|\int_K g dm-\int_K g_ndm| \leq \int_K|g-g_n| dm \leq \int |g-g_n| dm \to 0$]. Now apply this to $K=\{x:g(x) >M+\epsilon \}$ and $K=\{x:g(x) <M-\epsilon \}$ to conclude that (in each case $K$ has measure $0$ and $\epsilon$ is arbitrary so) $|g| \leq M$ a.e..